# How to use tilde '~' and back sign ' ` ' with motospeed ck62

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout

I'm using the motospeed ck62 keyboard with the layout English(US, international, with dead letters). But I couldn't find where I input the signs '**~**' and '**`**'

I'm using ubuntu and I need those simbols for my work (access home and SQL Athena) and I speak pt-br too so I need these accent for my daily communication too.

Comment: You should probably check the keyboard documentation, I'd guess. Looking at this keyboard on Amazon it appears to be short a few rather important keys. You may have to use key remapping, replacing other characters. There are plenty of guides how to do this already though.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> = `~`

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> = `` ` ``

Answer (score 0):

Hello fellow brazilian!

I had the same issue with the exact same keyboard model. What I did was install a key remaper. I found this one (don't know the developers neither the program, so use it at your own risk): https://atnsoft.com/keyremapper/

I set my right Alt to work as a "`". If I need a "~", I can just use "Left Alt" + "Right Alt".